# \vdots between two parallel arrows in \xymatrix

Tags: arrows, xymatrix

I have the following code

```
\xymatrix{a\rtwocell^f_g{\omit}&b}
```

and the result is two arrows from a to b, I want to put \vdots between the two arrows, exactly in the middle (to indicate there are many arrows from a to b). Could anyone help with this?

Other methods not using `\xymatrix or \rtwocell` producing horizontal parallel arrows with 3 vertical dots between them is also welcome and is fine for me. What I want is roughly as follows (but I want it to be more symmetric):

[image]

Comment: Maybe start here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved your problem using `tikz-cd` putting `\vdots` between the two arrows. I have used sometimes `xymatrix`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
Y_{n-1} & Y_n \arrow[l, "d_0"', bend right=42] \arrow[r, draw=none, "\raisebox{+1.5ex}{\vdots}" description]\arrow[l, "d_n", bend left=42] \arrow[r, "s_0", bend left=42]
\arrow[r, "s_n"', bend right=42] \arrow[l, draw=none, "\raisebox{+1.5ex}{\vdots}" description] & Y_{n+1}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution using `xypic` (and the useful `\raisebox` command sugested by @Sebastiano). Observe that the vertical dots are aligned with arrow labels.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\begin{document}
$\xymatrix@C=1.5cm{
    Y_{n-1} & 
    Y_n \ar@{}[r]|-{\raisebox{+1.5ex}{\vdots}}\ar@{}[l]|-{\raisebox{+1.5ex}{\vdots}}
        \ar@/_2ex/[r]_-{s_n} \ar@/^2ex/[r]^-{s_0} \ar@/_2ex/[l]_-{d_0} \ar@/^2ex/[l]^-{d_n} &
    Y_{n+1}
}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sigur I really thank you with my heart for quoting my name. Obviously your skill is unexceptionable and you deserve to be given +1.